# Plone: extracting i18n strings from dexterity xml models

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm working with dexterity xml models and am looking for a way to extract i18n strings from my models. It doesn't look like i18ndude or infrae.i18nextract do this. As a result all the translations strings in my xml models don't show in the generated .pot files.

Some of the models have more than 30 fields, so manual extraction is becoming tedious.

Comment: i18ndude extract msgid from Generic Setup XML files without problems so I don't get why it must not work on other XML files.
Maybe you are not defnining the domain? Can you edit your question adding a piece of your XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**i18ndude** do extract i18n messages from model files without any issues; check you're including your domain and marking the strings to be extracted.

see our [i18n script](https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/blob/master/buildout.cfg#L53) and check compare, as an example, [collective.cover's model](https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/blob/master/src/collective/cover/models/cover.xml) with yours:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<model xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/schema"
       xmlns:form="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/form"
       xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
       i18n:domain="collective.cover">
    <schema>
        <field name="template_layout" type="zope.schema.Choice"                   form:widget="collective.cover.widgets.selectpreview.SelectFieldWidget"
               form:omitted="z3c.form.interfaces.IEditForm:true">
            <description i18n:translate=""
              >Choose one of the predefined layouts</description>
            <title i18n:translate="">Layout</title>
            <vocabulary>collective.cover.AvailableLayouts</vocabulary>
            <default>Empty layout</default>
        </field>

        <field name="cover_layout" type="zope.schema.Text"
               form:omitted="z3c.form.interfaces.IForm:true
                             z3c.form.interfaces.IAddForm:true
                             z3c.form.interfaces.IEditForm:true">
            <description i18n:translate=""
              >The layout to be used to render groups and tiles</description>
            <title i18n:translate="">Cover Layout</title>
        </field>
    </schema>
</model>
```

Comment: Thanks hvelarde, will look at that. In the meantime I rubbed up an awk oneliner:

awk -F'"' '/translate/ { print "msgid \"" $2 "\"" "\nmsgstr \"""\""  }' mymodel.xml